# С помощью map добавить в объект внутри массива новое поле VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть массив объектов, в каждый объект я хочу добавить несколько новых ключей со значениями с помощью `map` внутри `created()`.

Массив такой:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '.movies',
    data: {
        movies: [
            {
                movie: "Метро",
            },
            {
                movie: "Мстители",
            } 
        ]
    },
    created() {
        var newMoviesArray = this.movies.map(function() { 
            
        })
        //добавить поля: like: true, seen: true, showDescription: true        
    }
});
```

Читала документацию про map, но мне легче ориентироваться на пример..Такого примера, который бы подошел мне, я , к сожалению, не нашла..

Comment: `this.movies.map((movie) => { return { like: true, seen: true}})`, в результате будет возвращен новый объект содержащий указанные поля

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `map` принимает callback-функцию, которая принимает 3 аргумента ([подробнее о них в документации по Array.prototype.map на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)), первый из которых содержит текущий обрабатываемый элемент.

Чтобы не модифицировать исходный объект, нужно создать новый, и скопировать в него все свойства исходного. А затем записать в него нужные свойства и вернуть, используя `return`.
В этом случае `newMoviesArray` будет содержать объекты с добавленными свойствами, а объекты в this.movies не будут изменены.

```
var newMoviesArray = this.movies.map(function(current) { 
let movie = Object.assign({}, current);
    movie.like = true;
    movie.seen = true;
    movie.showDescription = true;
    return movie;
});
```

Если вам всё таки нужно изменить объекты в this.movies, можно записать свойства прямо в `current`

```
this.movies.map(function(current) { 
    current.like = true;
    current.seen = true;
    current.showDescription = true;
});
```

Нужно заметить, что, поскольку объекты в JavaScript передаются по ссылке, объект, содержащий другие объекты или массивы, не будет скопирован корректно.
Например

```
let movie = {
    movie: "Мстители",
    actors: ["Роберт Дауни-младший"]
}

let copy = Object.assign({}, movie);
copy.actors.push("Крис Эванс");

console.log(copy.actors); // выведет ["Роберт Дауни-младший", "Крис Эванс"]
console.log(movie.actors); // выведет ["Роберт Дауни-младший", "Крис Эванс"]
```

Фактически это один массив, потому что в объект `copy` была скопирована только ссылка на массив, но не сам массив. То есть оба объекта ссылаются на один массив. Учтите это, если нужно копировать объект, который содержит другие объекты

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы именно добавить новые поля, необходимо воспользоваться помимо метода map еще и спред оператором, дабы сохранить предыдущие поля у каждого объекта

```
var newMoviesArray = this.movies.map((item) => { 
            return {...item, like: true, seen: true, showDescription: true}
        })
```